# How can I recover formatting of application's info.plist in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, plist, target, duplication

I duplicated default build target.
Some code files are duplicated also.
Problem is, duplicated info.plist file is not formatted by Xcode.

I don't think this is normal. Any workaround?
Or any way to specify formatting of plist? (which may format other type of .plist by my custom formatting rules)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Contextually (right- or control-) click both files and select the "Open as" -> "source file" option to view them as text. You can then (visually) diff them to determine what changed (and fix it).